# Response.Cookies["path"].Value = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString(); error Object reference not set to an instance of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Please help me actually i want that if the user is login then user can check the
 course info otherwise it directs to  login page and then come back to courseinfo
 page but after login it gives the error

My code is 
aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Secret for Management/MasterPage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Course_info.aspx.cs" Inherits="Secret_Course_info"
Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />
<meta name="Author" content="MominaNisar ()" />
<meta name="MominaNisar" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="Description" content="CENTER MANAGEMENT" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="CENTER ,MANAGEMENT" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Default.aspx" accesskey="c"><span         
class="key">H</span>ome</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Management.aspx" accesskey="g"><span class="key">
    M</span>anagement</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/student.aspx" accesskey="s"><span     
 class="key">S</span>tudent</a></li>
<li class="active"><span class="key">C</span>ourse</li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Exam_schedule.aspx" accesskey="x">Exam<span 
 class="key">  
    S</span>chedule</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Notice_Board.aspx" accesskey="n"><span class="key">
    N</span>otice Board</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Visiter_info.aspx" accesskey="n"><span class="key">
    V</span>isitor</a></li>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu_left" runat="Server">
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Course_of_Management.aspx" accesskey="n"><span
    class="key">M</span>anagement</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Course_of_Computer_science.aspx" accesskey="f">       
<span
    class="key">C</span>omputer Science</a></li>
<li><a href="../Secret for all user/Course_of_Other.aspx" accesskey="F"><span 
class="key">
O</span>ther</a></li>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Leftcol610" runat="Server">
<h3>
    Courses Info
</h3>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pn" DefaultButton="btnSubmit" runat="server">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="active">
                        Course Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Course_Name" runat="server" />
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"    runat="server" 
   SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="Course_Name">*
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="active">
                        Course Duration :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Course_Duration" runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
  SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="Course_Duration">*  
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="active">
                        Course Qualification :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Course_Qualification" runat="server" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
      SetFocusOnError="True"   ControlToValidate="Course_Qualification">*
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="active">
                        Course Total Fees :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Course_Total_Fees" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
   SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="Course_Total_Fees">*  
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="active">
                        Course Fees Method :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Course_Fees_Method" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
    SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="Course_Fees_Method">*  
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active" colspan="3">
       <asp:Label ID="lblerror" CssClass="popuptitle" Style="color: Red" runat="server"
                            Width="465px" Visible="False" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="active" colspan="3" align="center">
                        <asp:Button Text="SUBMIT" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
                             onclick="btnSubmit_Click" Visible="False" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </asp:Content>




   aspx.cs


 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Secret_Course_info : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader rea;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null)
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString() == "admin")
        {
            btnSubmit.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnSubmit.Visible = false;
            lblerror.Visible = true;
            lblerror.Text = "::This Page Only For Administrator::";
        }
    }
    else
    {

        Response.Cookies["path"].Value = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
        /* now after login i want that it reverts to the page but it gives the error object reference is not set to instance of the type*/
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
  }
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    int total;
    total = 0;
    String strcon = "Data Source=localhost;Initial   
    Catalog=Student_BioData;user=aaa;pwd=123;";
    string strsql = "select * from Courses ";
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = strsql;
        rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rea.Read()) { total++; }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) { lblerror.Text = ex.Message.ToString(); }  

    total += 1;
    try
    {
     strsql = "Insert into Courses values('"+
       Course_Name.Text.Trim()+ "','" +
        Course_Duration.Text.Trim() + "','" +
        Course_Qualification.Text.Trim() + "','" +
        Course_Total_Fees.Text.Trim() + "','" +
        Course_Fees_Method.Text.Trim()+ "')";
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = strsql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblerror.Visible = true;
            lblerror.Text = " Data Save In Courses info ";
      }
    catch (SqlException ex) { lblerror.Text = ex.Message.ToString(); }   
     }
   }



  stack trace


    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
     Loginpage.btnLogIn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Momina\installed     
    setup\Center Management\Center Management\Login.aspx.cs:53
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler
   .RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10

      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String   
       eventArgument) +13
         System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
        System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,
        Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563





   it gives error like
    //Response.Redirect("UpdateProfile.aspx");
    Line 52:             Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text;
 Line 53: Response.Redirect(Request.Cookies["path"].Value.ToString());//herecomes error 
         Line 54:         }
        Line 55:         else


    login.aspx

   <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Loginpage" Title="Loginpage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />
<meta name="Author" content="Momina Nisar " />
<meta name="Momina Nisar " content="index,follow" />
<meta name="Description" content="STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="STUDENT,MANAGEMENT" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<li><a href="Default.aspx" accesskey="h"><span class="key">H</span>ome</a></li>
<li><a href="Management.aspx" accesskey="g"><span class="key">M</span>anagement</a>     
</li>
<li><a href="student.aspx" accesskey="s"><span class="key">S</span>tudent</a></li>
<li><a href="Course_Infor.aspx" accesskey="c"><span class="key">C</span>ourse</a></li>
<li><a href="Exam_schedule.aspx" accesskey="x">Exam<span class="key"> 
S</span>chedule</a></li>
<li><a href="Notice_Board.aspx" accesskey="n"><span class="key">N</span>otice Board</a>
</li>
<li><a href="Visiter_info.aspx" accesskey="n"><span class="key">V</span>isitor</a></li>
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu_left" runat="Server">
<li><a href="Login.aspx" accesskey="l"><span class="key">L</span>ogin</a></li>
<li><a href="Contas_us.aspx" accesskey="u"><span class="key">C</span>ontact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="Feedback.aspx" accesskey="f">Feed<span class="key">B</span>ack</a></li>
</asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Leftcol610" runat="Server">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Login</legend> 
<div class='container'>
<asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text="UserName:" CssClass="lbl"/>
<br/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Height="22px"/>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RV1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtUserName" 
                        ErrorMessage="Please Enter User Name" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True">*
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
 </div>

 <div class='container'>
 <asp:Label ID="lblPwd" runat="server" Text="Password:" CssClass="lbl"/>
 <br/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                     CssClass="pwd" Height="22px"/>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RV2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtPwd" 
                        ErrorMessage="Your Password" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True">*
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
 </div>

  <div class='container'>
   <asp:Button ID="btnLogIn" runat="server" Text="Sign In" 
                      onclick="btnLogIn_Click"/>
  </div>

 <div class='container'>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl="~/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot Password ?</asp:HyperLink>
 <br/>
 </div>
 <div class='short_explanation'>New User ? 
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl="~/Createuser.aspx">SignUp !</asp:HyperLink></div>                       
  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" 
                   runat="server" CssClass="error"/>
  <br /><br />
   <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lbl"/>
   </fieldset>
   </asp:Content>

    login.aspx.cs

  using System;
  using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Security;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
  using System.Xml.Linq;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Mail;

   public partial class Loginpage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Login1.Focus();


      }
    protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    String strCon = "Data Source=localhost;Initial     
     Catalog=Student_BioData;user=aaa;pwd=123;";
    string strSelect = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM integrate WHERE UserName = @UserName AND 
    Password = @Password";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strSelect;

    SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    username.Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(username);

    SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    password.Value = txtPwd.Text.Trim().ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(password);

    con.Open();
    int result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    if (result >= 1)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        //Response.Redirect("UpdateProfile.aspx");
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text;
        Response.Redirect(Request.Cookies["path"].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
        lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password";
     }
    }
```

Please help me actually i want that if the user is login then user can check the
 course info otherwise it directs to  login page and then come back to courseinfo
 page but after login it gives the error

Comment: It's Not clear question. Sorry i can't understand !

Comment: See my below answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16183779/2218635

Comment: Narrow down the problem. No one's going to read that amount of code.

Comment: suppose  the user is opening the course page to see course info i want to chck that if the user is login then user can access  page else it goes to loginpage through "  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");" first login then revert to the page from where it goes to login page by using this

Answer (score 0):

Check for null reference

```
Response.Cookies["path"].Value = Request.Url != null ? Request.Url.AbsolutePath : string.Empty;
```

or

```
Response.Cookies["path"].Value = Request.UrlReferrer != null ? Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath : string.Empty;
```

Comment: The problem is with these lines of code                                     if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null)
{if (Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString() == "admin"){
btnSubmit.Visible = true;}}
    else{
Response.Cookies["path"].Value = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");}